# Bots are able to mint in candy machine bypassing whitelist tokens?

Tags: solana, metaplex, candy-machine

This is a question related to the Metaplex candy machine.

I noticed that bots are able to mint bypassing the whitelist tokens.

This is a whitelist config I had:

```
{
    "price": 1,
    "number": 777,
    "gatekeeper": null,
    "solTreasuryAccount": "REDACTED",
    "splTokenAccount": null,
    "splToken": null,
    "goLiveDate": "29 June 2022 00:00:00 GMT",
    "endSettings": null,
    "whitelistMintSettings": {
        "mode" : { "neverBurn": true },
        "mint" : "REDACTED",
        "presale" : true,
        "discountPrice" : 0.01
    },
    "hiddenSettings": null,
    "storage": "arweave",
    "ipfsInfuraProjectId": null,
    "ipfsInfuraSecret": null,
    "nftStorageKey": null,
    "awsS3Bucket": null,
    "noRetainAuthority": false,
    "noMutable": false
}
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set ur presale to true and goLiveDate is on the past. When you set presale: true means that whitelistSettings will be aplied before goLiveDate but when goLiveDate happens your mint will not be a presale and will be a public mint.

You can set presale: false so ur mint will be a whitelistMint (will be using goLiveDate as mint start date) or you can set goLiveDate to a date in the future and keep using presale: true, so ur mint will be a whitelist presale mint till the goLiveDate is met.

Make sure to run update_candy_machine after changing and saving ur config file.

Also take a read to the [whitelist settings examples on the official docs](https://docs.metaplex.com/candy-machine-v2/configuration#whitelist-settings) so you can have more info about this.